# Java Mail API is taking long time when sending Email to several recipients

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using Java Mail Api to send mail to 3 recipients, here's the code:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
                    message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
                    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                        InternetAddress.parse(emailTo));

                    message.setSubject("SUBJECT");           
                    message.setText(etext, "UTF-8");        
                    Transport.send(message);
```

**emailTo** is a String which contains all the recipients separated with commas, it takes at least 10 seconds to send the mail, but when there's only one recipient in the variable it sends the mail instantly.

Is there a way to optimize this part of the code or would it be better to use an alternative approach?

Comment: I would start debugging to find out where the time is spent.  If the network takes that much time to send the emails, for whatever reason (DNS lookups, latency, bandwidth etc.) then that's the time it takes. Moving to a better hosting provider could be an option.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in your mail server.  Turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) and watch the output in real time to see if there's some step that causes the mail server to take a long time to respond.  Try using different recipients, or the same recipient three times, to see if one of the recipients is causing the mail server to respond more slowly.